# Is there any way to remove the red circle from the Steps Recorder?

Tags: windows-10, problem-step-recorder

As the title says, is there any way to remove the red circle that appears after each mouse event (with the Microsoft Steps Recorder recording)?

[image: Steps]

Comment: Why would you need to do this, short answer is No.

Comment: No, because it's counter-intuitive. If I record something, I (as a user) expect some kind of feedback that confirms my recording. Stop recording, if those circles bother you.

Comment: @Moab I was using another software to record the screen and the steps recorder just to create a report. So this kind of red circle was unnecessary.